# Is 'performFetchWithCompletionHandler' called when no internet connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate

Will the `UIApplicationDelegate` call `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` if device is not connected to the internet ? The documentation isn't clear in this case.

Comment: `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is called by the system to give your app some processing time to update itself. It has no bearing on download fails. Are you not referring to `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests I can claim that `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` delegate method is not called if device is not connected to the internet.
Tested on iOS8 and iOS9.

Answer (score 0):

`-application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` isn't called when a download has completed. It's called by the system to give your app a chance to download data. You do normal error handling as you see fit.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSURL *URL = // Your URL
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle Error
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
            return;
        }

        // Process the data
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }] resume];
}
```