# How can I make sure that the user of my iOS app is alerted when internet connectivity is lost when the app is not active?

Tags: ios, push-notification

My app's main function is to configure and receive push notifications from a cloud service when the service detects alert conditions. When the app is inactive (background or not running) I want the user to be alerted when the internet connection has been lost, so that they know they might be missing notifications. How can this be done in iOS?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197630/ios-reachability-notification-in-background

Comment: Answer is no, you cannot run this type of code when your app is not in foreground :(

Comment: @BencePattogato thanks. I've tried the suggestion of testing the internet connection using background fetch mode, but I haven't worked out whether performFetchWithCompletionHandler even gets called at all if there's no network connectivity.

Comment: If this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221077/3708242) is to be believed, it is not called if there is no network connectivity.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to send a periodic "heartbeat" silent push. Schedule a local notification for, say, 10 minutes time and then send a silent push every 5 minutes. When the silent push is received, reschedule the local notification for 10 minutes time.  If the 10 minutes is reached without a heartbeat push resetting it then it will be fired and notify the user that something is up.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks I can see that working. I also thought of issuing an HTTP GET on transition to background, that the server takes forever to respond to, on a background-mode NSURLSession with huge timeout. On activation the app would cancel it, and on network break it would complete with failure and wake the app. Anyone know if this would work?